# Discrepancy with the output of `ls -al` and `getfacl`

Tags: chmod, acl, 18.04

I have run the following script to set permissions into /etc/nginx

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo chown -R root:root /etc/nginx
sudo chmod -R 0750 /etc/nginx
sudo setfacl -Rbk -m g:baa:rwx /etc/nginx
sudo setfacl -R --mask -m g:www-data:rx /etc/nginx
```

However, when I check the permissions afterwards there is a discrepancy in the results for the 'group' of `ls -al` and `getfacl`

```
$ ls -al /etc/nginx
total 24
drwxrwx---+   5 root root 4096 Mar 18 17:07 .
```

---

```
$ getfacl /etc/nginx
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: etc/nginx
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:www-data:r-x
group:baa:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
```

Why?

Comment: Because `ls -l` doesn't show _access control list_ attributes. It merely shows their pure existance by means of the `+` sign. That is: whenever you see a `+` in the permissions, issue `getfacl` afterwards.

Comment: Doesn't getfacl list the POSIX permissions too though? Isn't that what `group::r-x` is in the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see with `ls` is the `mask` entry of the ACL. From `man setfacl`, the `mask` entry seems to reflect the maximum possible permissions that can be set on an ACL entry.

> the permissions of the mask entry are further adjusted to include the union of all permissions affected by the mask entry

The access rights you see in your example with `ls` for the default group `root:rwx` are wrong as the effective rights are now controlled by the ACLs.

Comment: Crazy stuff, I guess it's meant to do that?

Comment: Yes, it is meant to do that. I just found the description in "CORRESPONDENCE BETWEEN ACL ENTRIES AND FILE PERMISSION BITS" in `man acl` (same as on https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man5/acl.5.html) But I was irritated as well.